# Signtool modified the Powershell code while signing

Tags: windows, powershell, code-signing, codesign, signtool

We use signtool.exe to sign our Powershell scripts. Recently, we came across a weird issue where signtool removed last of line of Powershell code and then added the signature block.

For example, this is our script

```
function Method
{
    ...
}
```

After signing, this became

```
function Method
{
    ...

# SIG # Begin signature block
...
# SIG # End signature block
```

Notice how the closing parenthesis `}` is removed from the file. We tried to reproduce the issue, but could not. My question is there a known issue with Signtool that intermittently causes this problem?

Edit: Found the issue. Apparently, Signtool puts (Signature block + one new line above the signature blob) while signing. The file before signing was having a signature already but with no new line between the code and the signature block. (Still investigating why). So, when our file did not have a new line, signtool replaced the closing parenthesis with new line.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't human error? Assuming you can't reproduce it even on the same script.

Comment: This whole thing runs in an automated workflow and no humans are involved. @kabanus

Comment: This happened only once since we started signing 4 months ago.

Comment: @kabanus Identified the root cause. See my edit.

Comment: Should put that as a self answer rather than an edit and accept tomorrow. Good find!